# Cant we read data from an established port using C# or python?

Tags: sockets

I used netstat to find which ports are established and I tried to read from an established connection using ip and port. I am getting the following error.

> Connection actively refused by the machine

Answer (score 0):

No - you can only create a connection to a listening port. "Established" means there is already a connection between two sockets. You can't add a third socket to an existing connection.

If you want to eavesdrop on the connection, there *are* ways to do that - on Linux, you can create a SOCK_RAW or AF_PACKET socket to receive all packets. On Windows, you need to install the WinPcap or Npcap driver and use libpcap.

If you are just curious and don't need to intercept the connection from a program, you can also use the open source tool Wireshark to see what data your computer is sending and receiving.

Comment: "*On Windows, you need to install the WinPcap or Npcap driver and use libpcap*" - you don't *need* to. You can just create a `SOCK_RAW` socket and enable the [`SIO_RCVALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sio-rcvall) option on it.